# How to create expression tree returning restricted set of properties, based on convention?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I need to create an expression tree returning `Expression<Func<TDataStructure, Double[]>> expression`. Tricky part about it, is that `TDataStructure` is generic  what implies, that each passed class contains different set of properties. I need to get properties of type `Double?` and names starting with specific string, like `"output"`.

Simple example case (concrete class):

```
Expression<Func<ConcreteDataStructure, Double[]>> expression =
    structure => new Double[] {
         structure.inputProperty1.Value,
         structure.outputProperty1.Value,
         structure.outputProperty2.Value
    };
```

where: `structure.inputProperty1.Value`, `structure.outputProperty1.Value`, `structure.outputProperty2.Value` are of type Double?

My case:

1. I do not know how many properties of type `Double?` are in `TDataStructure`
2. I need to get only these of type `Double?`, starting with `"output"`
3. Expression will be used in `IQueryable<TDataStructure> Select` method for projection of each sequence element into new form.

Comment: Both 1 and 2 can be solved with reflection: look at `Type.GetProperties()` or `TypeInfo.GetProperties()` (depending on which reflection API you're using).

Comment: This, I know. But I don't know how to use it in Expression.
var properties = typeof (TrainingData)
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(property =>
                    property.PropertyType == typeof (Double?)
                    && !property.Name.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("product"));

Comment: @Marek: Right, so once you've found the properties you want to use, you can use `Expression.Property` to build an expression for each of those properties...

Comment: Yes, but do you know what method should I use to create an `Expression` returning Array: `Expression<Func<input, Double[]>>` ?

Comment: I know, that I can do 
`ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDataStructure));
            Expression<Func<TDataStructure, Double>> expression
                = Expression.Lambda<Func<TDataStructure, Double>>(
                    Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "PropertyName"), typeof(Double))
                    ,param
                    );`
for each of properties...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, Double[]>> BuildExpression<T>()
{
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression[] array = typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("input") || p.Name.StartsWith("output"))
        .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
        .Select(p => (Expression)Expression.Property(Expression.Property(param, p), "Value"))
        .ToArray();

    Expression body = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(Double), array);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Double[]>>(body, param);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this:

```
static Expression<Func<T, double[]>> DoublePropertiesSelector<T>()
{
    var data = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, double[]>>(
        Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(double),
            from property in typeof(T).GetProperties()
            where property.PropertyType == typeof(double?)
            select Expression.Property(Expression.Property(data, property.Name), "Value")),
        data);
}
```

If you are okay with possible null-refs, in case your `double?` has no value.